# How can I summarise selected items in a tick-box grid of information in Google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a two-dimensional grid of information ([link to actual sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bucCwcXC9yTuliA1MMrki8QKEpsOGYnBpYk4ERcr_Dc)), like so:

[image: two-dimensional grid of information]

As you can see, there are items (money, time, and so on) that might be selected for each year. The items are grouped into categories, necessities and luxuries.

I want to produce a compact summary of selected items, that also groups items according to their categories, like this:

[image: summary of items]

I think that I need something that includes `xlookup()`, but I can't see how I would get the category information too.

Any suggestions on what approach to take? I don't mind too much about the format of the summary, as long as it respects the order of the years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `reduce()` and `filter()`, like this:

```
=let( 
  years, D3:F3, 
  input, filter(B4:C, len(B4:B) + len(C4:C)), 
  checkboxes, filter(D4:F, len(B4:B) + len(C4:C)), 
  data, let(a, input, s, sequence(rows(input)), array_constrain(bycol(a,lambda(v,map(s,lambda(i,index(xlookup(i,s/(v<>""),v,,-1)))))),rows(input),columns(a))), 
  raw, reduce("Summary", years, lambda(acc, year, let( 
    cur, filter(data, filter(checkboxes, years = year)), 
    if(iserror(cur), 
      acc, 
      ifna(vstack( 
        acc, 
        year, 
        filter(data, filter(checkboxes, years = year)) 
      )) 
    ) 
  ))), 
  map(sequence(rows(raw)), lambda(i, 
    if(i > 1, 
      if(index(raw, i, 1) = index(raw, i - 1, 1), 
        hstack("", choosecols(index(raw, i), 2)), 
        index(raw, i) 
      ), 
      index(raw, i) 
    )       
  )) 
)
```

See
[let()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13190535),
[filter()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093197),
[reduce()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12568597),
[map()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12568985),
[lambda()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718),
[vstack()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13191461),
[hstack()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13190756),
[choosecols()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13197914)
and
[sequence()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9368244).

Comment: Astounding, if I could give this multiple up-votes, I would. Thank you!